# Continuity of a peculiar function

Tags: limits, continuity

I came across the question: Evaluate$f(x)=\lim_{m \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}[\cos(n!\pi x)]^{2m}$.
I simplified this to: $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x \in Q$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x\notin Q$} \end{cases}$$
Is this function continuous?

As far as I know, if the limit of the function at a point $x=a$ equals $f(a)$, then the function is continuous at $x=a$. In this case however, how does one decide whether the limit is 1, 0, or does not exist?

Comment: Your distinction should focus on whether $x$ is integer or not, not on it being rational/irrational. In the case of an integer $x$, this is just $1$, yes. In the case of almost all irrational $x$, the inner limit $n\rightarrow\infty$ does not exist I am pretty sure. Are you sure about the order of the limits? Things would be different if $m \rightarrow\infty$ was on the inside. Your last paragraph is very fishy too.

Comment: @GDumphart: If $x$ is rational, then for $n$ sufficiently large, $n!$ will contain all prime factors of the denominator of $x$, and hence $n! x \in \mathbb N_0$.

Comment: @GDumphart Well for rational $x$'s eventually the denominator is canceled out by the $n!$. So I think the OP is right there. The issue is irrational $x$'s where very probably the inner limit does not exist.

Comment: @cfh Oh, you guys are correct of course.

Comment: I think @DRF is right that the inner limit doesn't exist for irrational $x$; it basically looks like some pseudo-random generator. With the limits in $m$ and $n$ swapped, things would be different.

Comment: @cfh Actually I think for some irrationals you might still get a limit. Suppose you define an irrational number in such a way that it is 1.01001000100001 etc. with increasingly long stretches of 0's which are smartly positioned so that from some point onward the n! always gives us a number increasingly closer to an even integer. Not sure it can be done but certainly not sure it can't.

Comment: @cfh Actually you might be able to define such a number in terms of some smart sum of factorial reciprocals?

Comment: I posted a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244778/closeness-of-n-x-to-integers-for-irrational-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments to your question, we have discussed that your first $f$ cannot be your second $f$. However, if we just look at
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x \in Q$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x\notin Q$} \end{cases},
$$
this is a well-defined function and we can think about whether it's continuous in some point $x$ or not.

First, assume that $x \in \mathbb Q$, so $f(x) = 1$. Then, for any $\epsilon>0$, you can find an irrational number $y$ with $|x-y| < \epsilon$ (for instance by choosing $y = x + \frac1n \sqrt2$ with a large enough natural number $n$). But then $|f(x) - f(y)| = 1$ even though $|x-y|$ can be arbitrarily small.

On the other hand, if $x \notin \mathbb Q$, we can use that the rational numbers are dense in the real numbers to find a $y \in \mathbb Q$ with $|x-y| < \epsilon$ for any small $\epsilon$ we like. Again, $|f(x) - f(y)| = 1$.

In both cases, if you refer to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, this shows that $f$ is not continuous in $x$. Thus, $f$ is a function which is continuous **nowhere**.

Comment: I'd like to add that this is known as the Dirichlet function (usually shown as an intuitive example for a non-Riemann-integrable function, but Lebesque integration gives $0$). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function

Comment: Oh look, my Wiki link even contains the problem of the question and, like I suggested, the limits are taken the other way around.