# Closeness of $n! \ x$ to integers for irrational $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

This question came up in the comments to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244752/continuity-of-a-peculiar-function).

Is there an irrational number $x$ such that, for sufficiently large $n$, the product
$$ n! \ x $$
is arbitrarily close to an integer?

More formally: does there exist an irrational number $x$ and an integer sequence $(a_n)$ such that
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} | a_n - n! \ x | = 0.
$$

Comment: Perhaps (?) rather

$$
  \liminf_{n\to\infty} | a_n - n! \ x | = 0
$$

Comment: @SimonS nah for the other question we would need the limit is actually 0. liminf wouldn't work. Even worse really you would want that the integer sequence is even or odd.

Comment: I didn't read the original question carefully enough. I was thinking of an arbitrary irrational number. That is: for any irrational $x > 0$, does there exist a sequence of integers such that $
  \liminf_{n\to\infty} | a_n - n! \ x | = 0
$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the number $e=\exp(1)$ is such a number. Also, maybe [more famously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) $\exp(-1)$.

Comment: Hehe I was thinking about something like it. The sum works out nicely canceling successive factorials. Though the convergence is surprisingly slow I guess? Only 1/n after n. Can you make sure you only get close to even numbers? I think the same trick might work with smart choices of the sum?

Comment: Ahh stupid question I suppose 2e works right? since you get all the things which aren't fractions are multiples of 2?

Comment: @DRF: For $n^{-2}$ convergence, try $\cos(1)$or $\sin(1)$.

Comment: New question, then: Can one give a simple necessary and sufficient condition for $x$ to be such a number?

Comment: @columbus8myhw Interesting question but it sounds rather evil. I would be happy with actually figuring out how much you can control the properties of $\lfloor n!x\rfloor$ (being even, odd, prime whatever).

Comment: @DRF (Well, $\operatorname{nint}(n!x)$ is closer to what OP meant, I think, where nint is the nearest-integer function. Which has no standard notation for some reason.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw fair point. I used floor mainly because the $e$ example ends up being floor.

Comment: Actually my comment about $\cos(1)$ and $\sin(1)$ is (or suggests something) **wrong**. While the sequences of distances of $n!x$ to the nearest integers contain sub-sequences (selected by parity of $n$) that converge as$~n^{-2}$, the remaining terms spoil that speed of convergence. In fact it looks as if it is impossible (for irrational $x$) to have convergence essentially more rapid than $n^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

I have accepted Marc van Leeuwen's answer. For those who want to see more details (as did I):

We have
$$
 e = \exp(1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1 {k!},
$$
and hence
$$
 n! \ e - n! \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1 {k!} = 0,
$$
from which we get
$$
  n! \ e - a_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac 1 {k!}
$$
with the integer sequence
$$
  a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}.
$$